# Change Planner in MoveIt Python

Tags: python, moveit, planner, robot, ompl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys, i want to change the default motion planner from OMPL in MoveIt to "PRMkConfigDefault".
But how can i change for example the planner for planning my group: `group = MoveGroupCommander("manipulator")` in Python? Thanks for your answers! Im running ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255792/change-planner-in-moveit-python/) by [Rhemus](https://answers.ros.org/users/29419/rhemus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2017-02-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the MoveGroupCommander.set_planner_id() function for this. Have a look at the [API documentation](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/moveit_commander/html/classmoveit__commander_1_1move__group_1_1MoveGroupCommander.html#a51bc4850dbeecbe086a0d1e90c2981b6)

An example:

```
group = moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander("manipulator")
group.set_planner_id("PRMkConfigDefault")
```

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2017-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rhemus](https://answers.ros.org/users/29419/rhemus/) on 2017-02-28**:
Thanks that worked well!